# How to use Select query for table names with parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, parameters, sql-injection

When an **Insert** query is used, parameters will work just fine because it is for values, but if I were to use parameters for **Create** or **Select** query for table names, it just wont happen because apparently table names has to be static.

#For example

```
 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("create table @1 ([BACK_LANG] varchar(50)");
                    myCommand.Connection = myDatabase;
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", this.getName()); //it was already set
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I do need to use **Select/Create** query with parameters, because I'll be selecting from the table they have created.

Sadly I couldn't come up with a solution and had to use non-parameter way, which is vulnerable to SQL Injections, the google search I've done past days didn't help me.

How do i use Create/Select Queries in SQL Server with .NET for table names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass an object name as a parameter directly to the statement like that. You can still use a parameter but the command will have to be something like this:

```
(@"declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'create table dbo.'
   + QUOTENAME(@1) + N'([BACK_LANG] varchar(50));';
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;")
```

Or just build the string in C#, using [`SqlCommandBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder)'s `QuoteIdentifier(this.getName())` which provides similar protection as `QUOTENAME()`.

For more on SQL injection: [Dynamic SQL](https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql)